# Android - configuring Facebook application

Tags: android, facebook

I have to integrate facebook in my application, and I have a problem when creating the `Facebook Application`, namely:
My application's `packageName` as found in the `AndroidManifest.xml` is overriden by the `gradle` file config.

Basically, in `AndroidManifest.xml` I have `com.myapp.smth`, and in `gradle` file I have `com.smth.myapp`.

So now, I don't know what to fill in the Facebook console for:

- package name -> which one? as defined in Manifest or as overriden by gradle?
- mainActivity name -> do I have to replace the package to the one overriden by gradle?
- keyHashes -> if I use the method described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488560 I get a **different** keyhash, than I would get if I were to use the method using command-line `keytool`. **Why is that?**

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

package name in gradle `com.smth.myapp`

mainActivity does not matter

keyHashes search in log by "TAG"->

```
try { SHH
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "YOUR_PACKAGE",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("TAG:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(),  Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```